# ASP.NET MVC Angular routing

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm lost..

For days now, i have tried to get it to work.. I made a MVC site code first with EF. then i've scaffolded controllers and API (tried ALOT thins)

my routeConfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

my WbApiConfig:
     config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

What should my Controllers actions return? json? views?

my ng-app is in my /Home/Index (which uses layout, and layout has ng app on html)

and at last, my ngApp

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Home/Index',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/Home/About', {
        templateUrl: '/Home/About',
        controller: 'programsCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

So.. the furthest I've got is a 404 or angular crashing chrome by loading infinitly.

And with the code above, i get the angular load more than one crash.

I just want my angular to load my views inside the ng-view and leave the layout on always..

ANY help or pointer appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use UI router, You create a one controller name 'HomeController' inherited from _layout. Your index view of Home contains this div

```
  <div ui-view></div>
```

You app.js file looks like, don't forget to add ui-router js in layout

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider

        .state('Home', {
            url: "/Home",
            controller: "mainController",
            templateUrl: "your html pages" // like '/script/home/templates/home.html'
        }).state('About', {
            url: "/Home/About",
            controller: "programsCtrl",
            templateUrl: "your html pages" // like '/script/home/templates/about.html'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: Module 'ui.router' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. - i copied your code and this is what i get

Comment: Add module name of your imported ui router js. (its module name mention in ui-router js), i already mention you to not to forget to add ui router js.

Comment: you don't need ui.router - you can just use `ng-route`

Comment: Thanks Ric, you made the day -.-

Answer (score 0):

The way I go about this is by setting the default for MVC to `home/index` and placing the `<ng-view></ng-view>` in the `home/index` view. This should be the only content in that view, remove everything else.

Now, on your `_layout`, make sure you have:

`<html ng-app="app">` at the top of the file and ensure that you have the relevant scripts loaded ie:

`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")`

So that angular is available.

Keep this for `@RenderBody()`

```
<div class="body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Your `MVC` methods return `ActionResult` (`return View()`) and your `ApiController` methods return `JSON`

Comment: It keeps saying angular loaded more than once and crashing

Comment: It shouldn't crash just because of that. are there any other errors in your console?